# Is it possible to leverage monadic structure if multiple monads are "mixed"?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Consider the following code:

```
run = runExcept $ do
  case Just 1 of
    Nothing -> throwE "escape 1"
    Just x -> do
      case Just 2 of
        Nothing -> throwE "escape 2"
        Just y -> do
          case Just 3 of
            Nothing -> throwE "escape 3"
            Just z -> return z
```

Pretend the `Just 1`, `Just 2`, `Just 3` are function calls that return `Maybe Int`.

This whole function is inside an `ExceptT` because I want to throw exceptions. But inside is really just a lot of `Maybe` values being manipulated.

So, is it possible for me to leverage the behaviour of a `Maybe` monad to avoid the stair-casing while still being able to throw exceptions?

Comment: You may like the `errors` package, which offers, among other things, [`note :: a -> Maybe b -> Either a b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.1.2/docs/Control-Error-Util.html#v:note).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you want to enrich a sequence of `Maybe` actions with information pertaining to *which one failed*, if any. Why not implement *enriching* as a simple function?

```
enrich :: MonadError e m => e -> Maybe a -> m a
enrich e Nothing = throwError e
enrich e (Just x) = return x
```

I'm using [`MonadError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#t:MonadError) - the class of monads `m` which can throw errors of type `e` - to generalise the type of `enrich`. For example, we can use it as if it had the type `e -> Maybe a -> Except e a` or `e -> Maybe a -> Either e a`, because `Except` and `Either` are both instances of `MonadError`.

Now you just need to use `enrich` to lift your `Maybe` values into the richer monadic context one at a time.

```
action = do
    x <- enrich "escape 1" maybe1  -- look mum, no staircasing!
    y <- enrich "escape 2" maybe2
    z <- enrich "escape 3" maybe3
    return [x, y, z]
```

---

If you're using your monad *applicatively* - that is, you're not using earlier results to determine later computations - there's an idiomatic way to generalise this function to work over an arbitrary number of `Maybe`s. We're going to shove the `Maybes` into a list, along with the extra data we need to enrich it - in this case, the error message. Then we can [`traverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse) (née [`mapM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM)) the list to enrich each `Maybe` inside it and join them up into a bigger monadic action.

```
enrichMaybes :: (Traversable t, MonadError e m) => t (e, Maybe a) -> m (t a)
enrichMaybes = traverse (uncurry enrich)

action = enrichMaybes [("escape 1", maybe1), ("escape 2", maybe2), ("escape 3", maybe3)]
```

The ability to treat effects as first-class citizens like this is why functional programming is a Good Thing.

Comment: Idiomatic as it is, I can't stand `zip [n..]`. If `lens` is about, I'd use `itraverse`. Otherwise, I'd write my own `traverseWithIndex` for lists.

Comment: @dfeuer What don't you like about it?

Comment: It doesn't really express the idea directly, and it's not so good for list fusion (only one of the lists can fuse away, and in recent GHC only the first).

Comment: @dfeuer I think you're right in this instance: incorporating the logic to template the error message into `enrichMaybes` was distracting from the point which was to illustrate `traverse`. I've adjusted the answer accordingly. (In general I do think `zip [1..] xs` is quite a clean way of saying it.) I've Googled a bit and I can't find any discussion as to _why_ `zip` only fuses one of its arguments, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I believe the reason only one can fuse is discussed in the original "a short cut to deforestation" paper. I successfully lobbied to stop attempting to fuse the second argument (trying only the first) because trying to fuse the second can potentially introduce bottoms (which is always bad) and in a fragile manner (which is especially bad).